# How to convert training data to test data for weka classifier?

Tags: classification, weka, training-data

I have training data (.arff) and i want to convert to test data.

this is my training data:

```
@relation fix_labeled_tweet

@attribute Text string
@attribute class-att {relevant,not_relevant,additional}

@data
'pvj dengan ciwalk masih tetap jadi tempat fav untuk belanja;',additional
'deta di bandung trade centre btc fashion mall;',additional
'promo hotel bandung ibis trans studio enjoy our special price akan your wonderful weekend periode s di 27 desember;',not_relevant
'indri  theressa di cihampelas walk ciwalk;',additional
'beiga we  di jatinangor town square jatos;',additional
'nonton di paris van java my husband;',relevant
'mainya seringnya ke paris van java mall miko mall mana;',not_relevant
'double date yeahhhh  di braga city walk;',relevant
'sinta di jatinangor town square jatos;',additional
'terimakasih tas dompet teguh di cihampelas walk ciwalk;',additional
'malam minggu miko the movie di cinema 21 mall panakukang;',additional
'karaokean sekalian dugem patriot  handrian di inul vista paskal hypersquare;',relevant
'makan di mujigae korean resto ciwalk;',relevant
'just posted a photo bandung trade center;',additional
```

What i've tried is removing the label (addition,relevant,not_relevant) from the data, then i save to different name, but it's not working. Weka said that the train and test set are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

They are incompatible because the structure of the training set and testing set is different.

If you did a copy of the document (say as Testing.arff), then supplied it as the test set, then the classifier would accept the file fine.  If, however, you remove the used attributes from the testing file, then the document cannot be used either because some of the inputs (for classification) or outputs (for evaluation) are missing.

I have been able to replicate your issue when removing the class output, but when copying the document, the test set works correctly as expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If he is worried about the class attribute being available in the test file, I would recommend replacing the actual labels in the data with ?.  That indicates missing values in an .arff, and the files would have the same structure.  http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html